# Force use Cellular Internet in Wear OS programmatically

Tags: java, android, wear-os, cellular-network

I am developing a chat app for Wear OS by Google. I am testing the app on 4G watches with Wear OS (Tic Watch Pro 4G).

The problem: When the watch is connected to parent mobile phone (Android or iOS), it uses the Internet through the parent device over Bluetooth connection. It happens even though the watch has its own 4G connection. Most of the time the Internet speed over Bluetooth is very slow and hence most of the API requests are timed out. The watch prefers Bluetooth even if it connected to a high-speed WiFi network. This watch's behavior is making it difficult for users to use the app.

Ideal Solution: The watch should use 4G or WiFi for Internet connectivity even when it is connected to Parent mobile phone over Bluetooth.

Codes tried so far:
Used a code to switch to WiFi or Cellular internet on app start

```
networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        if (bindProcessToNetwork(network)) {
            // socket connections will now use this network
        } else {
            // app doesn't have android.permission.INTERNET permission
        }
    }
};

NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)
    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
    .build();

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
```

The code above works successfully for WiFi, i.e. after using this code, the watch starts using WiFi for Internet even when it is connected with parent device over Bluetooth. After the code runs, the callback method (onAvailable) is called with the WiFi network.

But the code is NOT working when the watch needs to switch to 4G for the Internet. in the case of 4G, the callback method (onAvailable) is not called.

I have followed the code on below link but no success:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access

Please help.